# Aggregate String Concatenation in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I'm using Oracle 10 g, I have a scenario similar to this:

No  Name
--  -----
1   Rony
1   James
1   Aby
2   Sam
2   Willy
3   Mike

I need to aggregate and concatenate the strings (with a single space in between), in a way to get the results:

No  Name
--  -----
1   Rony James Aby
2   Sam Willy
3   Mike

I'm using Oracle 10g and have to implement this using SQL and not PL/SQL. Is there a way out?

Comment: Several [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wm_concat+listagg)

Comment: @Arjun did you find you solution. I have modified my answer to match for 10g.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy on 11G, you can use the LISTAGG function, but sadly not on 10G

There are some techniques here for earlier versions however they do require a function to be written.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
select No  , rtrim(Name,',') Name
   from ( select No , Name , rn from yourtable
           model
  partition by (No)
  dimension by (row_number() over
 (partition by No order by Name) rn
 )
 measures  (cast(Name as varchar2(40)) Name)
   rules
 ( Name[any] order by rn desc = Name[cv()]||' '||Name[cv()+1]
   )
  )
    where rn = 1
    order by NO
```

Here is your sql  [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a5d1/12)

Comment: `LISTAGG` is not supported in oracle10g

Comment: @Horrendous_Space_Kablooie yes thanks i thought it was 11g. now its done.

Comment: Is it possible to turn this into a reusable function, to permit usage like... `select no, gconcat(name) from mytable;`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LISTAGG

see [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f728/2)

Comment: This became available with 11g.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **SQL** query

```
SELECT 
  [No],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + Name
    FROM #tbl_concat 
    WHERE ([No] = Results.[No]) 
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,0,'') AS NameValues
FROM #tbl_concat Results
GROUP BY [No]
```

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` is `T-SQL` (Microsoft SQL Server)