# Tag Database Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate, concatenation

I have three tables for tagging. The first one is the `question` table that has a list of question with certain ID. The second one is the `tag` table that has a list of tag name with certain ID. And the third one is the `question_tag` table, a collection of question to a tag. A question that has multiple tag means multiple rows in `question_tag`, I thought of storing an serialized array into the `question_tag` table but it's in general not a good idea to store array inside of a SQL database.

Below is the schema. Arrow denoting foreign key.

```
                       -------------------
-----------------      | question_tag    |      
| question      |      -------------------        ------------------
-----------------      | question_tag_ID |        | tag            |
| question_ID   | ---> | question_ID     |        ------------------
-----------------      | tag_ID          | <----- |  tag_ID        |
                       -------------------        |  tag_name      |
                                                  ------------------
```

I want to make a query that will output this table below.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| question_id | tag_name                           |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1           | algebra, calculus, differentiation |
| 2           | calculus                           |
| 3           | algebra, trigonometry              |
----------------------------------------------------
```

How do I manage to do this query? I thought about SELECTING from `question` and `JOINING` a temporary table of `SELECT tag.tag_name FROM tag WHERE question_tag.tag_ID = tag.tag_ID`, but how do I output this RIGHT column (tag_name) like the table above.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this SQL query, I am guessing that I need to do a nesting SELECT query for the RIGHT (tag_name) column, then JOIN it to the question_table. But I am not sure how to the nesting of SELECT query.

This is what I have come up with:

`SELECT * FROM question as Q LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.tag_name FROM tag as T WHERE T.tag_id IN (SELECT QT.tag_id FROM question_tag AS QT WHERE QT.question_ID = Q.id)) AS QT_T`

Comment: tags are mostly a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Hey neovee, We'd need to know what database system you're using to help you with the query. I have the same schema for an app I've created, but it's in SQL server. Please let us know.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I used MySQL, does the code differs a lot from the SQL server? Or at least does the concept that you use apply anywhere? Maybe I can manage to solve it in MySQL

Comment: See my update below. This is strictly going off of other reference material and has not been tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to aggregate and concatenate. Please check out some of the related questions:

[Does T-SQL have an aggregate function to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings)

[Implode type function in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534724/implode-type-function-in-sql-server-2000)

[Concatenate row values T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql)

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

[Aggregate String Concatenation in Oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312848/aggregate-string-concatenation-in-oracle-10g)

[Create a delimitted string from a query in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728010/create-a-delimitted-string-from-a-query-in-db2)

[How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

**UPDATE**

While I don't have a mysql DB to test this on, going off of one of the above links (with the knowledge this is mysql), I've designed the following query:

```
SELECT 
    qt.question_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM question_tag qt
LEFT JOIN tag t ON t.tag_id = qt.tag_id
GROUP BY qt.question_id;
```

Please try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: How do you now neovee uses SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Probably doesn't. My real answer is not the links it's the process that can be looked up. I'll update my answer when more info is provided.

Comment: @Bizorke I managed to do it like the way you suggested. The GROUP_CONCAT function is exactly what I needed